# How to render only anchor tags in v-html element and avoid others and show them as string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to render only the anchor tag and render other html tags as string inside my vue project ( in v-html ) attribute.

Something similar to Linkedin does. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5tj5.png)

I have tried to use linkifyjs library but couldn't figure out how I can show the link only on the dom.

Comment: Have you looked into Vue-Linkify?

Comment: @Ali This library is vulnerable, it allows you to inject any iframe or suspicious script inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) (named `myContent`) bound to an element's `v-html`:

```html
<div v-html="myContent"></div>
```

`myContent` should:

1. Replace all the `<` characters with `&lt;`, which escapes the HTML tags.
2. Using a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with a regular expression, replace all values of `href` and `src` attributes with anchor tags.
3. Invoke `linkifyjs` on the result to create links of any standalone URLs in the markup.

```js
import linkifyHtml from 'linkifyjs/html'

export default {
  computed: {
    myContent() {
      const markup = this.html
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/((?:href|src)=['"])(.*?)(['"])/g, (matched, prefix, href, suffix) => {
          return `${prefix}<a href="${href}" target="_blank">${href}</a>${suffix}`
        })

      return linkifyHtml(markup, { target: { url: "_blank" } })
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/linkifying-hrefs-in-a-string-forked-eyqc5?file=/src/App.vue)